# Python : Capitalize first character of words in a string except one word

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list-comprehension

I have string `a = 'thirteen thousand and forty six'`. The variable `a` would always hold some amount in words. I want to capitalize first characters of each word in the string, except the specific word `'and'`. Here is my code which is working fully :

```
b = []
for i in a.split():
    if i.lower() == 'and':
        b.append(i.lower())
    else:
        b.append(i.capitalize())
aa = " ".join(b)    #'Thirteen Thousand and Forty Six'
```

Another piece of oneliner I tried is :

```
aa = " ".join([k.capitalize() for k in a.split() if k.lower() != 'and'])
```

but, it returns `'Thirteen Thousand Forty Six'` as the resultant string, omitting the word `'and'`.

Question is whether there are any possible oneliners using list comprehension or some inbuilt functions (without using regex) for this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax should be

```
aa = " ".join([k.capitalize() if k.lower() != 'and' else k for k in a.split()])
```

When you put your `if` clause at the end of comprehension it will skip elements that don't satisfy the condition. Your requirement, however, is to return the item verbatim when it is `"and"`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting on the default (`split()`) why not split on the " and ", and re-join using "and" as well?

```
aa = " and ".join([word.capitalize() for word in a.split(" and ")])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet might be useful, It simply gives the desired output in single line python code:

```
s = 'thirteen thousand and forty six'
print(s.title().replace('And', 'and'))
```

Comment: There is one problem with using this code, even though it completes the purpose, is that if there is any single quote mark in the string like "thirteen t'nd and forty six"; it would return "Thirteen T'Nd and Forty Six" with the character immediately next to the single quote in caps.

Comment: @michaelpetronav Thanks for noting this bug; to meet the purpose, we can use 
 s = string.capwords(s, sep=' ').replace('And', 'and') instead.

Answer (score -1):

you could just replace "And with and" after capitalizing

```
a = 'thirteen thousand and forty six'
(' ').join([x.capitalize() for x in a.split(' ')]).replace('And', 'and')
```